# Как в Electron передать информацию для сохранения в диалог сохранения файла?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winapi, electron

При вызове диалога сохранения файла, в него не передаются параметры с информацией, как сохранить данные в файл?

Comment: Добавьте ваш пример кода. Возможно вы не дочитали документацию и упустили какую-то важную деталь или не проверяете типы данных.

Answer (score 1):

Сам разобрался.
Оказалось все очень просто, диалог сохранения просто возвращает выбранный путь, а записывать файл надо уже самому по этому пути.

Comment: Понял суть вопроса только когда прочитал ответ )